# Is it Possible to render Radio Buttons / Checkboxes in multiple columns in a row using Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to render Radio Buttons in multiple columns using row css class in a form. what i want is if its a tablet or bigger screen it should display three radio buttons per row else one. below is code from my project for that and it works fine with a small issue, I am getting this awkward space between rows. any idea how to remove the spacing or any alternative way achieve my requirements.

**Updates**

to clarify more

if you check the bootply created by ganders in the comments below you would see that there is some padding between rows, how can I remove that padding between rows, I want it to be more like a table with zero cellpadding and cellspacing. when you reduce the browser size to render small screen you would see that first three radios in the first row renders fine and next row has some margin/padding at top.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">What is your Department?</label>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="terrible" /> Terrible
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="terrible" /> Terrible
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="terrible" /> Terrible
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="terrible" /> Terrible
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="terrible" /> Terrible
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="terrible" /> Terrible
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**more updates**

I manage to achieve that, below code is working for me, I don't know if its the right to do it as I am very new to bootstrap.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">What is your Department?</label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="padding:0px;">
                        <div class="radio" style="margin:0px;">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="terrible" /> Terrible
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="padding:0px;">
                        <div class="radio" style="margin:0px;">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="terrible" /> Terrible
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="padding:0px;">
                        <div class="radio" style="margin:0px;">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="terrible" /> Terrible
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="padding:0px;">
                        <div class="radio" style="margin:0px;">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="terrible" /> Terrible
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="padding:0px;">
                        <div class="radio" style="margin:0px;">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="terrible" /> Terrible
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="padding:0px;">
                        <div class="radio" style="margin:0px;">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="terrible" /> Terrible
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: hows this [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/coozin/wtw6g2n7/) look? can you be more specific on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: At what point are you getting the bad spacing? Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: copying and pasting your exact code into a bootply shows that it's working correctly, based on how you worded your question. What are you not telling/asking us? http://www.bootply.com/vqp1GZD0nq

Comment: guys if you check the bootply created by ganders you would see that there is some padding between rows, how can I remove that padding between rows, I want it to be more like a table with zero cellpadding and cellspacing. I have also updated the question put my question in a better way.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/eqqcehwd/1/ check this